# Determining where the function $f(z) = \frac{y+ix}{x^2+y^2}$ is (complex-)differentiable

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

> Determine at what points the function
>   $$f(z) = \frac{y+ix}{x^2+y^2}$$
>   is differentiable, and write the formula for $f'(z)$ at those points.

Should I let $u = y+ix$ and $v = x^2 + y^2$ and then use the Cauchy-Riemann equation?

Comment: Take the derivative

Comment: Which kind of derivative are you supposed to take? The complex is not possible (as already mentioned by Henry W.). Or are you sopposed to decide whether $f$ is complex differentiable?

Comment: I need  to determine at what point the following functions are differentiable and write the formula for f'(z) at those points

Comment: Then choose $u(x,y) = y/(x^2+y^2)$ and $v(x,y) = x/(x^2+y^2)$, because then $f = u + iv$.

Comment: @user108698 I've rewritten the question to reflect your clarifications in the comments. If something doesn't reflect your intentions, please edit/revert as appropriate.

Comment: Notice $f=\frac z{|z|^2}$.

Comment: @HenryW. : Would you dispute my answer below? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy $\frac{1}{z}$ is not holomorphic. It is differentiable everywhere except for the origin though.

Comment: @HenryW. : So it is holomorphic on the set $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If you're not restricted to using the CR equations, you can solve this by writing the numerator as $i(x - iy) = i \bar{z}$ and the denominator as $(x + iy)(x - iy) = z \bar{z}$.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that someone posed this problem in a context in which it was specified that $z=x+iy$ and $x$ and $y$ are real, and "differentiable" means with respect to $z=x+iy$.  I wouldn't pose this question outside such a context.

It probably couldn't hurt to know that $\dfrac{y+ix}{x^2+y^2} = \dfrac 1 {y-ix} = \dfrac 1 {-i(x+iy)} = \dfrac i {x+iy} = \dfrac i z$.

The quotient rule tells us that $z\mapsto\dfrac i z$ is differentiable.

Given the way the problem was phrased, I wouldn't be surprised if explicit use of the Cauchy–Riemann equations was intended.  However, being aware of the other things I mention above is also worthwhile.